# why JSTL forEach do not complete loop?

Tags: jsf, foreach, jstl

I have a xhtml file that loops trhough some items and for each item includes a xhtml which loops to display some items:

```
    file-a.xhtml
    <c:forEach var="record" items="#{firstItemsList}">
      do some stuff...
      <ui:include src="file-b.xhtml" />
    </c:forEach>
```

In file be I have the following:

```
    #{viewController.resetComments()}
    <c:forEach var="item" items="#{comments}" varStatus="status">
      show some tags here...
    </c:forEach>
```

problem is that in the second or third or ... imports of the file-b within file-a, for each loop in file-b will loop through max number of comments which was in the first call. for example, if the first import ofcall for file-b has 3 elements in it and the second call for file-b has 5 elements in it, then forEach loop stops showing content on the 3rd index for the second call.  now if the first call has zero elements in it.. all other proceeding calls for file-b will show nothing even if they have comment items.

question is how can i make the forEach loop complete task correctly on each call for file-b?

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know why the loop is not working properly but i bypassed the problem by hard coding html fragment that forEach was generating in xhtml file inside java code in my controller. So in file B i have the following instead of the forEach loop.

```
    <h:outputFormat escape="false" value="#{controller.showComments(list)}" />
```